# group by for two conditions in mysql query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table dailyentry in this following structure with data

```
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| id |   date   |loan_id|daily_amt|
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| 1  |20-07-2014|   1   |   200   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 2  |20-07-2014|   1   |   300   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 3  |20-07-2014|   2   |   400   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 4  |20-07-2014|   2   |   200   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 5  |21-07-2014|   1   |   100   |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
```

I need to get each day `daily_amt` total for each `loan_id`. like this below.

```
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| id |   date   |loan_id|daily_amt|
+----+----------+-------+---------+
| 1  |20-07-2014|   1   |   500   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 3  |20-07-2014|   2   |   600   |
|    |          |       |         |
| 5  |21-07-2014|   1   |   100   |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
```

I tried to get it by `groub by date`. like this below,

`select *,sum(daily_amt) from dailyentry group by date`

This query result is showing like below.

```
+----+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
| id |   date   |loan_id|daily_amt|sum(daily_amt)|
+----+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
| 1  |20-07-2014|   1   |   500   |     1100     |
|    |          |       |         |              |
| 5  |20-07-2014|   1   |   100   |      100     |
+----+----------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

I hope some one already solve problem like this before. Please share some ideas.

Comment: You want to gorup by two elements?

Comment: yes... by date as well as loan_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select *,sum(daily_amt) from dailyentry group by date, loan_id
```

Comment: I tried with `group by date and loan_id` like this.. I missed to use `,` there... anyway thanks...